# Privilege page not updated with latest community wiki change

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

This still exists: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: Yeah... that second line of "when to use" would be an ideal thing to cut out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the heading *"When should I make my answers Community Wiki?"* should probably read something like *"How are questions and answers made Community Wiki?"*. Also, the part about automatic conversion would fit in here.

Lastly, the screenshot should be updated (or it should be made clear that this is how it looks for *moderators* — if that's the case ... I have no idea).